# how to update page after database insert or update in php or ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

A good example for that is like facebook. After someone comments another person then all can see the update pop up not just your own page and doesn't need refresh.. I'm making a project that monitors or filter out bad comments.. So if there is a bad comment inserted in the database then it gives me notification and pops out the data.. any help please.. thanks I use php for server side language.

Comment: Use AJAX to check for updates with a `setInterval`. Google's your friend.

Comment: you wrote ".. any help please.. " but if you don't commenting or replying then how any help will u get.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is always be a way.
you can use comet programming and long polling using ajax and php.

well drawback is that using comet your other http request will be Holt so for comet you must need to rewrite session that is best.

as per your question i would suggest you to use myisam engine because its tracking for timestamp when database is last modified so you will know when database is updated.

Sample comet code is as below.

**index.php**

```
<div id="content"></div>

<p id="form_container">
    <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="comet.doRequest($('#word').val());$('#word').val('');return false;">
        <input type="text" name="word" id="word" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Comet = function (data_url)
    {
        this.timestamp = 0;
        this.url = data_url;  
        this.noerror = true;

        this.connect = function()
        {
            var self = this;

            $.ajax(
            {
                type : 'post',
                url : this.url,
                dataType : 'json', 
                data :
                {
                    'timestamp' : self.timestamp
                },
                success : function(response)
                {
                    self.timestamp = response.timestamp;
                    self.handleResponse(response);
                    self.noerror = true;          
                },
                complete : function(response)
                {
                    if (!self.noerror)
                    {
                        setTimeout(function(){ comet.connect(); }, 5000);           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.connect(); 
                    }
                    self.noerror = false; 
                }
            });
        }

        this.disconnect = function() {}

        this.handleResponse = function(response)
        {
            $('#content').append('<div>' + response.msg + '</div>');
        }

        this.doRequest = function(request) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type : 'post',
                url : this.url,
                data :
                {
                    'msg' : request
                }
            });
        }
    }

    var comet = new Comet('./backend.php');
    comet.connect();
</script>
```

**backend.php**

```
function get_date()
{
    $query = mysql_query("show table status from weefavr like 'request_responses'")or die(mysql_error());

    $row = array();
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $row[] = $result;
    }
    return strtotime($row[0]['Update_time']);
}

$lastmodif    = isset($_POST['timestamp']) ? $_POST['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = get_date();

while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif)
{
    usleep(10000);
    clearstatcache();
    $currentmodif = get_date();
}

$query_db = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update.created) AS DATE,last_update.* FROM last_update WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update.created) BETWEEN '".$lastmodif."' AND '".$currentmodif."'")or die(mysql_error());

$row_db = array();
$response = array();
while($result_db = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_db))
{
    $response['msg'][]       = $result_db['title'];
}

$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
$response['lastmodif'] = $lastmodif;
echo json_encode($response);
flush();
```

this example is quite helpful but as i told you your other HTTP request will not work.
so you need to do some hack regarding session and else.

and yes Facebook,g mail,asana and zaarly are big giant who are using comet programming.

Hope this will help.
Feel free to ask cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an AJAX request from your page to achieve that.

When the user performs an action you can submit an ajax request and dynamically update that user's page. Everyone else will also see this.

Comment: 'Everyone else will also see' - based of an action of a single user. Surely this requires everyone's page to be polling the server for updates?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice PHP/MySQL/AJAX tutorial and download available [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/) that should get you started.  Combine this with your server-side filtering logic and a periodic ajax callback to keep everyone's page updated and you should be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be PHP and Ajax.
In case you need it, a basic [introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp) is here.
Basically you need to have a webpage that via Javascript asynchronously polls your backend (PHP page) that serves new content. You could have a Javascript timer or even much more complex setups like the backend "pushing" to your page.
I'd advise you to check this other [page](http://matthewaprice.com/simple-jquery-ajax-auto-refreshing-div/) for an example.